# Why are vectors created by ':' integer?

Tags: r, types, integer, numeric

Why are vectors created using `:` of the type `integer` and vectors created using `c()` of type `double`?

```
a <- 1:7
typeof(a)
# "integer"
class(a)
# "integer"
b <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
typeof(b)
# "double"
class(b)
# "numeric"
```

Comment: I guess that was mainly a design decision. If you want to create an integer vector without using the colon operator, you can use `c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus I am confused because two vectors have same values but they are of different types.

Comment: They may look the same but they are not the same

Comment: Alternative methods of constructing the sequence of integers are `seq_len(7)` or `seq(1, 7)`.

Comment: Not all vectors created by `:` are integer: consider `1.5:8.4`

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly answering the **why**, but trying to shed some light on the **what**.
Let's start with creating some sequences of numbers:

```
x <- 1:10
z <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
typeof(x)
# [1] "integer"
typeof(z)
# [1] "double"
class(x)
# [1] "integer"
class(z)
# [1] "numeric"
```

As @docendodiscimus pointed out, they might look the same, but they are different. This is important if you check if they are identical:

```
identical(x,z)
# [1] FALSE
x == z
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

While `==` is a "Binary operator which allow the comparison of values in atomic vectors." (see `?==`), `identical()` is "The safe and reliable way to test two objects for being exactly equal. It returns TRUE in this case, FALSE in every other case." (see `?identical`).

This becomes even more striking when you compare the results of `seq()`

```
y1 <- seq(1,10) # which is the equivalent to 1:10 (see ?`:`)
y2 <- seq(1,10, by = 1)
typeof(y1)
# [1] "integer"
typeof(y2)
# [1] "double"
class(y1)
# [1] "integer"
class(y2)
# [1] "numeric"
```

Since the `by = ...` argument is missing [1 is assumed](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Generating-regular-sequences) and therefore a integer vector is sufficient to represent the sequence.

Besides being totally confusing, this might all be due to design issues (this is as close as I can get to the **why**).  Therefore, it is stated in the [help](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.html) that

> "programmers should not rely on which" [type or class the sequence is of]

However, the `mode` of all vectors is `numeric`

```
mode(y1)
# [1] "numeric"
mode(y2)
# [1] "numeric"
mode(x)
# [1] "numeric"
mode(z)
# [1] "numeric"
```

For more on this crazy behaviors you should have a look at [this section in The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf#subsection.8.1.65) (actually, the whole book is a good read).

**To work around this problem** you might consider coercing the `z` vector of *not so integery* integers to *true* integers by

```
z <- as.integer(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
typeof(z)
# [1] "integer"
class(z)
# [1] "integer"
identical(x,z)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: To add to the confusion, try `y3 <- seq(1, 10, by = 1L)` and `y4 <- seq(1L, 10, by = 1L)`.

Comment: seems "programmers should not rely on which" is in the doc for a good reason :)

Comment: You may also mention that from:to is equivalent to seq(from,to). This can make the answer more striking.